# How to do generic menus using select in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, menu

I [followed instructions in this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1705/how-can-i-create-a-select-menu-in-a-shell-script) to create a specific, four-option menu using `select`:

```
function showMenu() {
    PS3=$1
    shift
    options=("$@")
    select opt in "${options[@]}"
    do
        case $opt in
            ${options[0]})
                echo "${options[0]}"
                break
                ;;
            ${options[1]})
                echo "${options[1]}"
                break
                ;;
            ${options[2]})
                echo "${options[2]}"
                break
                ;;
            ${options[3]})
                echo "${options[3]}"
                break
                ;;
            *)  # just loop ...
                ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

This works well when invoked like this:

```
COLORS=("red" "blue" "green" "yellow")
COLOR=$(showMenu 'Choose a color' "${COLORS[@]}")
# if user inputs a '1', then COLOR would be blue
```

In a shell script, I need to have multiple menus and whereas I can write a function based on the number of options (e.g. 3, 4, 5 etc.), that function is essentially a copy of the same construct. Is there a way to write a generic menu that displays as many options in the `select/case` as there are values in the passed array?

For instance, how can I make a function with generic menu capacity that works *both* like above (for four colors) and like below (for five folders)?

```
FOLDERS=("foo", "bar", "baz", "too", "moo")
FOLDER=$(genericSelect 'Choose a folder' "${FOLDERS[@]}")
# if user inputs a '3', then FOLDER would be too
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your requirement with a sample output like, after providing an input for first menu, what script should be display on screen like any other menu or result.

Comment: @Krishna, I added relevant comments illustrating the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function showMenu() {
    PROMPT=$1
    shift
    options=("$@")
    numOptions=${#options[@]}
    read -p "${PROMPT}: " response
    echo "${options[$response]}"
}
```

Note that this is just bare bones - there's no error handling in there! :)